# How can I convert a SSL certificate from PEM to DER and keep the private key?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate, x509

Backstory: I have a PKCS#12 (p12) certificate with a symmetric cipher (password) that I used OpenSSL to convert to a PEM; opening that as text I see it contains both a `BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE` section as well as `BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY`.  The .NET Framework `X509Certificate` class only supports the "ASN.1 DER" format, so I used OpenSSL to convert the PEM to DER.  Unfortunately it appears doing this doesn't include the private key which is what I need for making an SSL connection with `SslStream` & `TcpClient`.

```
X509CertificateCollection certsFromFile = new X509CertificateCollection();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("my.der.crt");
if (!cert.HasPrivateKey)
    throw new Exception("No private key");
certsFromFile.Add(cert);

TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream(), false,
    null, null);
sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certsFromFile,
    SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
sslstream.Close();
tcpclient.Close();
```

How do I take this PEM file and make it into a DER while retaining the private key information so I can use it in .NET for signing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I'm behind the times!  Looks like `X509Certificate2` can read PKCS#12 files so there's no need for any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates and keys are generally stored separately. Cut the PEM file into two files, one with the certificate and one with the key. You can then use the openssl toolkit to convert each file separately into a DER file.